# Using multithreading to speed up web crawler written by beautifulsoup4 and python

Tags: python, multithreading, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am writing a web crawler to extract the information of a website. However, since I am using Beautiful Soup 4 to extract large amount of data on window, the crawling speed is extremely slow. Can Anyone tell me how to use multi threading in my case. Thank you so much if you wanna help me. My code is as below:

```
import requests
from html.parser import HTMLParser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import re
import time
import sys
import json


HTML_PARSER = "html.parser"



def get_shop_link_list(links):
global food_id
list_req=requests.get(links)
if list_req.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(list_req.content, HTML_PARSER)
    link_tag=soup.find_all('h2',{'class':'heavy break-word'})
    for h2 in link_tag:
        print(food_id,end="@")
        link=h2.find('a')
        parse_shop_information(link['href'])
        food_id=food_id+1
        print("")       
#turn next page
    try:
        next_page=soup.find('a',{'class':'button -small'})
        get_shop_link_list(next_page['href'])
    except KeyError:
        pass



def parse_shop_information(shop_link):
req=requests.get(shop_link)
if req.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, HTML_PARSER)

    #restaurant name
    shop_header_tags = soup.find('div',{'class' : 'cassette'})
    japname_tag=shop_header_tags.find('p',{'class':'small'})
    print(japname_tag.get_text(" ",strip=True).encode(encoding="utf-8",errors="strict").decode(sys.stdin.encoding).strip(),end="@")
    name_tag = shop_header_tags.find('h1',{'class' : 'jumbo break-word'})
    print(name_tag.get_text(" ",strip=True).encode(encoding="utf-8",errors="strict").decode(sys.stdin.encoding).strip(),end="@")
    #Basic information
    shop_body_tags = soup.find('ul',{'class' : 'icon-list -space sentence'})
    information = shop_body_tags.find_all('li')
    for li in information:
        print((li.get_text("|",strip=True).encode(encoding="utf-8",errors="strict")).strip(),end="{")
    #Detail information
    restaurant_detail = soup.find_all("table", {"class":"table sentence"})
    basic_detail=restaurant_detail[0].find_all('tr')
    address="No record"
    address_pic="No record"
    access="No record"
    parking="No record"
    service="No record"
    cards="No record"
    for tr in basic_detail:
        if tr.find('th').get_text(" ",strip=True)=='Address':
            address=((tr.find('p').get_text(" ",strip=True)))
            address_pic=((tr.find('img')["src"]))
        if tr.find('th').get_text(" ",strip=True)=='Access':
            access=((tr.find('td').get_text(" ",strip=True)))
        if tr.find('th').get_text(" ",strip=True)=='Parking':
            parking=((tr.find('td').get_text(" ",strip=True)))
        if tr.find('th').get_text(" ",strip=True)=='Service charge':
            service=((tr.find('td').get_text(" ",strip=True)))
        if tr.find('th').get_text(" ",strip=True)=='Cards Accepted':
            cards=((tr.find('td').get_text(" ",strip=True)))
    print(address.strip(),end="@")
    print(address_pic.strip(),end="@")
    print(access.strip(),end="@")
    print(parking.strip(),end="@")
    print(service.strip(),end="@")
    print(cards.strip(),end="@")

    try:
        facility_detail=restaurant_detail[1].find_all('tr')
        seating="No record"
        MPS="No record"
        RMPS="No record"
        Smoking="No record"
        WAR="No record"
        KF="No record"
        LS="No record"
        WP="No record"
        Other="No record"
        for tr in facility_detail:
            if tr.find('th').get_text(" ",strip=True)=='Seating Capacity':
                seating=((tr.find('td').get_text(" ",strip=True)))
            if tr.find('th').get_text(" ",strip=True)=='Banquet Maximum Party Size':
                MPS=((tr.find('td').get_text(" ",strip=True)))
            if tr.find('th').get_text(" ",strip=True)=='Reservation Maximum Party Size':
                RMPS=((tr.find('td').get_text(" ",strip=True)))
            if tr.find('th').get_text(" ",strip=True)=='Smoking':
                Smoking=((tr.find('td').get_text(" ",strip=True)))
            if tr.find('th').get_text(" ",strip=True)=='Wheelchair Accessible Restrooms':
                WAR=((tr.find('td').get_text(" ",strip=True)))
            if tr.find('th').get_text(" ",strip=True)=='Kid Friendly':
                KF=((tr.find('td').get_text(" ",strip=True)))
            if tr.find('th').get_text(" ",strip=True)=='Language Support':
                LS=((tr.find('td').get_text(" ",strip=True)))
            if tr.find('th').get_text(" ",strip=True)=='Wi-Fi  /  Plug-in':
                WP=((tr.find('td').get_text(" ",strip=True)))
            if tr.find('th').get_text(" ",strip=True)=='Other':
                Other=((tr.find('td').get_text(" ",strip=True)))
        print(seating.strip(),end="@")
        print(MPS.strip(),end="@")
        print(RMPS.strip(),end="@")
        print(Smoking.strip(),end="@")
        print(WAR.strip(),end="@")
        print(KF.strip(),end="@")
        print(LS.strip(),end="@")
        print(WP.strip(),end="@")
        print(Other.strip(),end="@")


    except IndexError:
        print("No record",end="@")
        print("No record",end="@")
        print("No record",end="@")
        print("No record",end="@")
        print("No record",end="@")
        print("No record",end="@")
        print("No record",end="@")
        print("No record",end="@")
        print("No record",end="@")

    try:
        other_detail=restaurant_detail[2].find_all('tr')
        menu="No record"
        lunch="No record"
        dress_code="No record"
        Delivery="No record"
        for tr in other_detail:
            if tr.find('th').get_text(" ",strip=True)=='Lunch Service':
                lunch=(tr.find('td').get_text(" ",strip=True))
            if tr.find('th').get_text(" ",strip=True)=='Dress Code':
                dress_code=(tr.find('td').get_text(" ",strip=True))

            if tr.find('th').get_text(" ",strip=True)=='Menu':
                lunch=(tr.find('td').get_text(" ",strip=True))
            if tr.find('th').get_text(" ",strip=True)=='Delivery / Catering':
                dress_code=(tr.find('td').get_text(" ",strip=True))
        print(menu.strip(),end="@")
        print(lunch.strip(),end="@")
        print(dress_code.strip(),end="@")
        print(Delivery.strip(),end="@")
    except IndexError:
        print("No record",end="@")
        print("No record",end="@")
        print("No record",end="@")
        print("No record",end="@")

    try:
        main_col_tag=soup.find('div',{'class':'global-navigation'})
        main_col=main_col_tag.find_all('li')
        for li in main_col:
            if li.find('a').get_text()=="Menu":
                print("{",end="")
                sub_menu(shop_link)
                print("}",end="")   
    except (IndexError, AttributeError):
        print("No record",end="@")



def sub_menu(link):
list_req=requests.get(link)
if list_req.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    soup=BeautifulSoup(list_req.content,HTML_PARSER)
    all_menu_tag=soup.find('ul',{'class':'-sub-menu hide'})
    menus=all_menu_tag.find_all('li')
    for i, li in enumerate(menus):
        type=li.find('a').get_text()
        print("\"",end="")
        print(type,end="\":[")
        link=li.find('a')
        sub_menu_json(link['href'])
        if i != len(menus)-1:
            print("]",end=",")
        else:
            print("]",end="")


def sub_menu_json(link):
list_req=requests.get(link)
if list_req.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(list_req.content, HTML_PARSER) 
    eachfood=soup.find_all('div',{'class':'cassette normal-colored'})
    for i,div in enumerate(eachfood):
        food_jap_name="No record"
        food_eng_name="No record"
        food_price="No record"
        tax_inclusion="No record"
        description="No record"
        if div.find('div',{'class':'small'}):
            food_jap_name=div.find('div',{'class':'small'}).get_text(" ",strip=True)
        if div.find('h3',{'class':'huge'}):
            food_eng_name=div.find('h3',{'class':'huge'}).get_text(" ",strip=True)
        if div.find('h3',{'class':'huge abit-spacing'}):
            food_eng_name=div.find('h3',{'class':'huge'}).get_text(" ",strip=True)
        if div.find('p',{'class':'small spacing'}):
            food_price=div.find('p',{'class':'small spacing'}).get_text(" ",strip=True)
        if div.find('span',{'class':'-value'}):
            food_price=div.find('span',{'class':'-value'}).get_text(" ",strip=True)
        if div.find('p',{'class':'text-right small'}):
            tax_inclusion=div.find('p',{'class':'text-right small'}).get_text(" ",strip=True)
        if div.find('div',{'class':'panel -light-silver -in'}):
            description=div.find('div',{'class':'panel -light-silver -in'}).get_text(" ",strip=True)
        if div.find('div',{'class':'sake-detail'}):
            description=div.find('div',{'class':'sake-detail'}).get_text(" ",strip=True)
        print("{\"JpnFoodname:\":",end="\"")
        print(food_jap_name.encode(sys.stdin.encoding, "replace").decode(sys.stdin.encoding).strip(),end="\",")
        print("\"EngFoodname\":",end="\"")
        print(food_eng_name.encode(sys.stdin.encoding, "replace").decode(sys.stdin.encoding).strip(),end="\",")
        print("\"Price\":",end="\"")
        print(food_price.strip().encode(sys.stdin.encoding, "replace").decode(sys.stdin.encoding).strip(),end="\",")
        print("\"TaxIncludeExclude\":",end="\"")
        print(tax_inclusion.strip().encode(sys.stdin.encoding, "replace").decode(sys.stdin.encoding).strip(),end="\",")
        print("\"Description\":",end="\"")
        print(description.strip().encode(sys.stdin.encoding, "replace").decode(sys.stdin.encoding).strip(),end="\",")
        if div.find('a') or div.find('img'):
            print("\"ImgUrl:\":",end="\"")
            if div.find('img'):
                food_pic=div.find('img')["src"]
            if div.find('a'):
                food_pic=div.find('a')['href']
            print(food_pic,end="\"}")
        else:
            print("\"ImgUrl:\":\"No record\"",end="}")
        if i != len(eachfood)-1:
            print(',',end="")



if __name__ == '__main__':
global food_id
food_id=1
get_shop_link_list("https://gurunavi.com/en/reg/pf_tokyo/rs/srh/?p=461")
```

Comment: I admittedly only skimmed through `get_shop_link_list`, but from what I see you're using a recursive approach to crawl the website. I'd suggest you to switch to an iterative approach (e.g., make a queue and enqueue the links as you discover them, dequeueing them and processing them one by one). You should also check that you don't loop visiting twice the same link (this will crash your recursive approach btw). With the queue set up, you can then spawn multiple threads dequeueing and processing the pages separately.

Comment: I suggest you to use **Scrapy**, it is built on Twisted, an asynchronous library, so you can browse large amount of data.

Comment: Yes, I understand that Scrapy is far much faster but the website I want to crawl is a bit complicated to use it.

Comment: – GPhilo, thank you for your advice but I I will not change it to iterative approach at this stage. Since I just want to know how to use multithreading to speed up the crawling speed, I will try your approach next time. :)

Comment: `os.fork()` the process maybe, looks you not need the data return for further parsing, just save the data in file or database separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an outline of what you can do; split the work into individual jobs, add the jobs to a jobQueue and start as many processes as you need (you pass the jobQueue to each one)

Each process takes one job from the queue as log as there are still jobs to process.

This way the number of workers is configurable

```
import multiprocessing,Queue

def getData(tasksQ):
    while (True):
        try:
            job=tasksQ.get(block = False)    
        except Queue.Empty:
            break;
        else:            
            <do_work>


tasks = multiprocessing.Queue()

for job in getJob():
  tasks.put(job)

noOfProcesses = 10
processes = []    
for i in range(noOfProcesses):
  p = multiprocessing.Process(target = getData, args=(tasks,))
        processes.append(p)

for p in processes:
    p.start()       

for p in processes:
    p.join()
```

Hope this helps.